# Winged Dragon of Ra's Attack and Defense Points

Tags: yu-gi-oh

On the card of the Winged Dragon of Ra, the attack and defense points are ????. I am wondering that does the Winged Dragon of Ra has infinite power, and if not, what are his defense and attack points?

Comment: It is important to note that the original prints of the Egyptian god cards, including "Winged Dragon of Ra" are not legal for play in Advanced or Traditional formats, as they are only promotional collector's cards. These are the ones with the flavor text and not the effects on them. The ones printed later, with the effects on them, are legal for play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winged Dragon of Ra has a special ability. Well, it has a lot of them. But the important one is this:

> When this card is Normal Summoned: You can pay Life Points so that you only have 100 left; this card gains ATK and DEF equal to the amount of Life Points paid.

So if you're at 3,500 life, you can choose to activate this ability leaving you with 100 life. Winged Dragon of Ra would then have 3,400 ATK and DEF, representing the 3,400 life you paid.

If you choose not to pay, then he enters as a 0 0. You can still activate his kill ability, although consider that you have to tribute 3 monsters to do it, so to even that out you'd have to pay 3,000 life. He's definitely a card you build around if you're going to play him.

Answer (score -4):

It's attack and defense are equal to the monsters you sacrificed added up

Comment: This was only true in the Anime series, as it was the way Marik played it